# I am not getting any Ipfs peers. Ipfs daemon is running but ipfs swarm peers show nothing?

Tags: ipfs

in first terminal

```
/Desktop/JOO$ ipfs daemon
Initializing daemon...
Adjusting current ulimit to 2048...
Successfully raised file descriptor limit to 2048.
Swarm listening on /ip4/10.14.13.31/tcp/4001
Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4001
Swarm listening on /ip6/::1/tcp/4001
API server listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001
Gateway (readonly) server listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/8088
Daemon is ready
```

In second terminal

```
/Desktop/JOO$ ipfs  swarm peers
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: i am not able connect to any peers.  what is the problem here?. what is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

See if you have any bootstrap peers:

```
$ ipfs bootstrap list
```

If not, then add a peer to the bootstrap list:

```
$ ipfs bootstrap add /ip4/25.196.147.100/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmaMqSwWShsPg2RbredZtoneFjXhim7AQkqbLxib45Lx4S
```

You can also restore the default bootstrap list:

```
 $ ipfs bootstrap add --default
```